# How to remove "higher/lower harmonics" from expression

Tags: fourier-analysis, trigonometry

let's say we are given $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cos(k \omega t)$. How can we tell Mathematica to neglect all terms in the above expression for which $k_1>k > k_0$, where $k_0$ and $k_1$ are specified?

Edit: For clarity, the command `Sum` is *not* part of the expression. Think of it as being already expanded (if that makes any sense). For example, you are given
$a_0 + a_1 \cos(\omega t) + a_2 \cos(2 \omega t)$, $k_0 = 0$ and $k_1=2$.  The result should then be $a_1 \cos(\omega t)$.

Comment: Why not use `FourierSeries[]` on your function?

Comment: Well, efficiency. To my understanding this takes way too long to evaluate.

Comment: Will a simple replacement do? E.g.  expression  /. Cos[k_ w t ] /; k0<k<k1 :> 0

Answer (score 1):

If `k0,k1,n`are known, you can adapt the index range of `Sum`

```
k0 = 5; k1 = 10; n = 15;
ki = Select[Range[0, n], ! (k0 < # < k1) &]
Sum[a[k],{k,ki}] (* for clarity Cos[...] omitted*)
(*a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[10] + a[11] + a[12] +a[13] + a[14] + a[15]*)
```

answer to the modified question:

```
k0 = 0; k1 = 2; n = 15;
ki = Select[Range[0, n], (k0 < # < k1) &]
Sum[a[k] Cos[k \[Omega] t], {k, ki}] 
(*a[1] Cos[t \[Omega]]*)
```

**"without Sum[]"**

```
k0 = 0; k1 = 2; n = 15;
expr=  Sum[a[k] Cos[k \[Omega] t], {k, 0,n}] ;
expr /. a[k_ /; ! ( k0 < k < k1 )] -> 0    
(*a[1] Cos[t \[Omega]]*)
```

Comment: I figured my question was misleading. I tried to clarify it. Sorry…

Comment: @freddy90 see my modified answer

Comment: I might miss something but how would this work without the `Sum` command?

Comment: @freddy90 Perhaps ` "your sum expression"  /. a[k_ /; ! ( k0 < k < k1 )] -> 0`